# Possibility of a phone to connect automatically to HC-05 when within range?

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

Sorry i am a beginner into bluetooth and arduino field but im currently looking into possibilities of connecting a HC-05 (ZS-040) bluetooth module to a phone (android) automatically when within range.

I am also creating an app (via MIT app inventor2) to turn a LED on/off via the app once the phone has automatically connected to the HC-05. Is the HC-05 right module for this ?

I am aware of the 'list picker' option via MIT app inventor to connect to the HC-05, however is there an alternative approach for an automatic connection to the phone ? What is the best possible approach for this kind of scenario ?

Regards
Kav

Answer (score 0):

According to what ı understand, I suggest you firstly to enable bt modules' 3.3v and gnd then diagnose with your phone. The password may be "1234" or "0000".

Comment: i have already paired the hc-05 with the phone. however it does not re-connect again. can the device function similar to a bluetooth headset of a car where when within its proximity the handset automatically connects to it ? or is there a way to program it ?

Comment: I think, the re-connection issue related with android system(android has 1:30 minutes for connection). I don't think it can have similar behaviour to bt handset.